# How to calculated the absolute value via of bit operations

Tags: bitwise-operators, absolute-value

In the *Hacker's delight*, there is an example of calculating the absolute value of `x` as `(х XOR (x >> 31)) - (x >> 31)`.

I know that `x >> 31` returns the sign of `x`. I understand Boolean algebra, but how does `(х XOR (x >> 31)) - (x >> 31)` work?

Comment: gcc currently uses this to implement integer absolute value on x86.  It's not actually the fastest way, though:  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the definition of [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), `-x = ~x + 1`

If `x` is negative: `y = x>>31 = -1`.  Rewrite the `~x` inversion as `x ^ -1`, and the `+1` to subtracting `-1`, to get:

```
-x = (x ^ -1) - -1 = abs(x)
```

If `x` is non-negative: `y = 0`, and `(x ^ 0) - 0)` is obviously just `x`.

Answer (score 0):

(x XOR y) - y is just doing 2's complement on a negative number. For positive number, y will be 0 so x remains unchanged.

Example. x = -2.

-2 is represented as 0xFFFFFFFE

x>>31 will make y = 0xFFFFFFFF (ie. -1)

x XOR y will flip all the bits in x giving result as 0x00000001

(x XOR y) - y = 0x00000001 - (-1) = 0x00000002.